# error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.8' failed with exit status 1 when installing spiff with linuxbrew

Tags: linux, gcc, homebrew, cloud-foundry, linuxbrew

I'm trying to install `spiff` on ubuntu 14.04.2 desktop, first I install linux brew:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/dzlab/.linuxbrew/bin
```

Then I try to install spiff:

```
$ brew install spiff
==> Installing spiff from xoebus/homebrew-cloudfoundry
==> Installing dependencies for spiff: mercurial, godep
==> Installing spiff dependency: mercurial
==> Downloading http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/mercurial-3.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/heavenize/.cache/Homebrew/mercurial-3.3.tar.gz
==> make PREFIX=/home/heavenize/.linuxbrew/Cellar/mercurial/3.3 install-bin
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.8' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [build] Error 1

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting
```

How I can fix this issue? is there another way to install spiff?

Answer (score 0):

Watch for the `^` symbol under `#include <Python.h>`. It points where the error occured. According to this output, GCC cannot find file 'Python.h'.